# Two update statements in a single stored procedure based on different IDs

Tags: sql-server

Would this be a bad practice to use two `Update` statements in a stored procedure to modify rows based on different IDs? In following case, two ids `@TipID` and `@TipDlvId` are used to update rows for single table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UPD_Tip]
    @TipId INT, 
    @TipDlvId INT,
    @UpdatedBy nvarchar(60),     
    @TipVal1 DECIMAL(5,2) = NULL,
    @TipVal2 DECIMAL(5,2) = NULL,
    @TipVal3 DECIMAL(5,2) = NULL,
    @TipVal4 DECIMAL(5,2) = NULL,
    @TipVal5 DECIMAL(5,2) = NULL,
    @TipVal6 DECIMAL(5,2) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE TIPS 
    SET IsDefault = (CASE 
                         WHEN @TipId = -1 THEN IsDefault 
                         WHEN @TipId = 0 THEN 0 
                         WHEN TipId = @TipId THEN 1  
                         ELSE 0 
                      END),
        DisplayName = CASE TipID 
                          WHEN 1 THEN 
                              CASE 
                                  WHEN @TipVal1 IS NOT NULL 
                                      THEN CONCAT(CAST(@TipVal1 * 100 AS int), '%') 
                                      ELSE DisplayName 
                              END
                          WHEN 2 THEN
                              CASE 
                                  WHEN @TipVal2 IS NOT NULL 
                                      THEN CONCAT(CAST(@TipVal2 * 100 as int), '%') 
                                      ELSE DisplayName 
                              END
                          WHEN 3 THEN
                              CASE 
                                  WHEN @TipVal3 IS NOT NULL 
                                      THEN CONCAT(CAST(@TipVal3 * 100 AS int), '%') 
                                      ELSE DisplayName 
                              END
                        END,
        TipValue = CASE TipID 
                        WHEN  1 THEN 
                            CASE WHEN @TipVal1 IS NOT NULL  THEN CAST(@TipVal1 * 100 AS money)/100 ELSE TipValue END
                        WHEN 2 THEN 
                            CASE WHEN @TipVal2 IS NOT NULL  THEN CAST(@TipVal2 * 100 AS money)/100 ELSE TipValue END 
                        WHEN 3 THEN 
                            CASE WHEN @TipVal3 IS NOT NULL then CAST(@TipVal3 * 100 AS money)/100 ELSE TipValue END
                    END,
        LastUpdated = GETDATE(),
        UpdatedBy = @UpdatedBy;

    UPDATE TIPS 
        SET IsDefault =  (CASE 
                               WHEN @TipDlvId = -1 THEN IsDefault 
                               WHEN @TipDlvId = 0 THEN 0 
                               WHEN TipId = @TipDlvId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
                           ),
        DisplayName = CASE TipID 
                        WHEN 4 THEN 
                            CASE WHEN @TipVal4 IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT(cast(@TipVal4 * 100 as int), '%') ELSE DisplayName END
                        WHEN 5 THEN
                            CASE WHEN @TipVal5 IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT(cast(@TipVal5 * 100 as int), '%') ELSE DisplayName END
                        WHEN 6 THEN
                            CASE WHEN @TipVal6 IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT(cast(@TipVal6 * 100 as int), '%') ELSE DisplayName END
                        END,
        TipValue = CASE TipID 
                        WHEN  4 THEN 
                            CASE WHEN @TipVal4 IS NOT NULL  THEN CAST(@TipVal4 * 100 AS money)/100 ELSE TipValue END
                        WHEN 5 THEN 
                            CASE WHEN @TipVal5 IS NOT NULL  THEN CAST(@TipVal5 * 100 AS money)/100 ELSE TipValue END 
                        WHEN 6 THEN 
                            CASE WHEN @TipVal6 IS NOT NULL then CAST(@TipVal6 * 100 AS money)/100 ELSE TipValue END
                    END,
        LastUpdated = GETDATE(),
        UpdatedBy = @UpdatedBy;
END
```

Comment: It's a matter of opinion but I would say that's an anti-pattern, you could and should combine that into a single update, you're httting the same table twice and updating the same rows twice. If it's 10 rows it's negligible, if it's 10m rows then, well....

Comment: Its going to be always 6 rows. Its kind of configuration which is fixed to 6 rows.

Comment: Then i would say whilst you can write a single statement, it's your call whether that's worth the effort for 6 rows, I'd say probably spend your time on more important stuff.

Comment: You are clearly using Microsoft SQL Server, not MySQL, so I changed the tags.

Comment: It's fixed at  6 until that point in time when it is decided it needs to be 7. This looks like it would be better off in the long being normalized.